# What does caret mean in MCS Synchronization Paper?

Tags: computer-science

The [original paper](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/papers/1991_TOCS_synch.pdf) does not read too difficult, but I just can't figure out the meaning of caret. It doesn't look like it is bitwise exclusive-OR.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doh, it means pointer. Now it all makes sense and is quite obvious.